# How to get rid of commas separators in Integer fields when using DBSchema SQL

Tags: java, sql, derby, db-schema

Has anyone come across this issue with DBSchema (connected to a Derby database) where Integer (and BIGINT) fields are displayed with a comma separator in them. You can see the effect in the bottom row of the attached image.

Any ideas how to turn this off?  I have gone through all the settings and can't find anything related.  The reason it is annoying is that it the fields are unix time fields and having commas as magnitude separators is a very distracting.

[image]

Comment: It looks like an update to DBSchema has been issued which fixes the above problem.  You can select the option to not show the thousands separators by going to Model->Settings->General

Answer (score 0):

The reason commas are being used as the thousands-separator is probably the **Locale** set in the JVM that's running DbSchema.

You can change it by adding these two lines to the **DbSchema.vmoptions** file located in the installation directory

```
-Duser.language=es
-Duser.country=ES
```

Here is a mapping of **Locale**s to **Decimal and Thousands separators** https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

For more details about **Locale** read https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/locale.html

Comment: Thankyou @Alessandro Leo, that was helpful but this will just replace the commas with the decimal point.   I would like to be rid of all separators altogether.   For example mysql workbench scripts return the raw integer values, for example 16224556745 etc